# Sequence generation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anybody suggest a fast algorithm for generating this
Triangle where the $k$-th item at $n$-th row (both starting from 1) tells in how many ways we can add $2$ distinct integers from $1$ to $n$, in such way that the sum is divisible by $k$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A061857

Comment: There's a Maple algorithm given there, no?

Comment: Not a complete one though... trinv is not defined.  And not fast because it's $O(n^2)$ to get one entry of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways $g(n,s)$ to add two distinct integers from $1$ to $n$ to get the sum $s$  is $\lfloor \dfrac{s-1}{2} \rfloor$ for $3 \le s \le n+1$ and $\lfloor n - \dfrac{s-1}{2} \rfloor$ for $n+1 \le s \le 2n-1$.  In time $O(n)$ you can compute this for each $s$ from $3$ to $2n-1$.  Then for each $k$ from $1$ to $2n-1$ you add $g(n,jk)$ for $j$ from $1$ to $\lfloor (2n-1)/k \rfloor$ in time $O(n/k)$, giving a row of the table in $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: thnx for reply  i made a code according to it bit still it is not that fast enough. i need to generate the no of ways for given n and k . the number of test cases are 100000 and n<=10^9 and 2<=k<=10^9.

#include<stdio.h>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
int main()
{
long long int n,k;
int t;
long long int i,j,s=0,m=0,l,p;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&k);
s=0;
p=n+1;
for(i=k;i<=p;i=i+k)
{
s=s+((i-1)/2);
}
m=(n+1)%k;
m=n+1-m+k;
l=2*n-1;
for(i=m;i<=l;i=i+k)
{
s=s+(long long int)((float)n-((float)(i-1)/2.0));
}
printf("%lld\n",s);
}
}

Comment: is their a way out

Comment: Your code seems to be for producing a single element of the table, rather than a whole row.  Which do you really want?  Also you're using the same index variable i in two nested loops.  Do you really want to do that?

Comment: Also note that e.g. if $k$ and $j$ are odd, $\lfloor \dfrac{jk-1}{2} \rfloor = \dfrac{jk-1}{2}$, otherwise $\lfloor \dfrac{jk-1}{2} \rfloor = \dfrac{jk-2}{2}$.